# Scrapy Post data to URL

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm attmepting to scrape http://www.regmovies.com/Theatres/Theatre-Folder/Regal-Meridian-16-1082 for all movies that are showing and return their imdb rating.

From scrapy shell I set the value:

`fetch('http://www.regmovies.com/Theatres/Theatre-Folder/Regal-Meridian-16-1082')`

`response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h3/text()').extract()`

The returned value is empty `>>> []` This is the last piece to building my spider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page use JavaScipe fetch data, you can find the data URL in Chrome Dev Tools's NetWork tab:

[image]

You should use Scrapy `Post` data to this URL:

[image]

```
In [9]: from scrapy.http import Request

In [10]: r = Request(url='http://www.regmovies.com/services/MovieListings.asmx/TheatrePerformances',
    ...:             method='POST',
    ...:             body='{"tmsId":"AABFY","date":"Sun Mar 19 2017"}',
    ...:             headers={'Content-Type':'application/json', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

In [11]: fetch(r)
2017-03-19 14:10:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.regmovies.com/services/MovieListings.asmx/TheatrePerformances> (referer: None)

In [12]: import json

In [13]: json.loads(response.text)
```

out:[image]